# How can I invert the colors of one window on macOS? (and not the entire monitor)

Tags: macos, display, color

I'm trying to invert the colors of one window, and not the entire monitor, on macOS.

- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> inverts the colors on all
  monitors.
- [Black Light](https://michelf.ca/projects/black-light/) only allows users to invert the colors on selected monitors, but selected windows.

How can I invert the colors of one window on macOS? (and not the entire monitor)